# File download works in the browser but not programmatically

Tags: java, file, download

I'm having some problem to download some file programmatically, but the same download works just fine in the browser.

The download starts and a file is downloaded, but it's size is wrong and all the information is corrupted. It should be just a XML file, but this is what happen when I try to open the file.

[image]

Here is the code:

URL is just a constant with a link which I change two parameters.

```
        Calendar dataFuturo = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataFuturo.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
        String urlFormatada = String.format(URL, StringUtils.dateParaString(new Date(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE),
                StringUtils.dateParaString(dataFuturo.getTime(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE));
        System.out.println(urlFormatada);
        System.out.println(StringUtils.dateParaString(new Date(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE));
        System.out.println(StringUtils.dateParaString(dataFuturo.getTime(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE));
        final String diretorio = SettingsUtil.getMessage(SettingsUtil.DIRETORIO_BACKUP) + "teste.xml";
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File(diretorio));
        System.out.println("Finished");
```

I've tried to download the file in many different way, but the result is always the same.

Another try:

```
        Calendar dataFuturo = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataFuturo.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
        String urlFormatada = String.format(URL, StringUtils.dateParaString(new Date(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE),
                StringUtils.dateParaString(dataFuturo.getTime(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE));
        System.out.println(urlFormatada);
        System.out.println(StringUtils.dateParaString(new Date(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE));
        System.out.println(StringUtils.dateParaString(dataFuturo.getTime(), StringUtils.DEFAULT_DATE));
        final String diretorio = SettingsUtil.getMessage(SettingsUtil.DIRETORIO_BACKUP) + "teste.xml";
        URL url = new URL(URL); //The file that you want to download
        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();//connect
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
            urlConn.connect();
            System.out.println("type: " + urlConn.getContentType());
            System.out.println("total size: " + urlConn.getContentLength());
            is = urlConn.getInputStream();               //get connection inputstream
            fos = new FileOutputStream(diretorio);   //open outputstream to local file

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];              //declare 4KB buffer
            int len;

            //while we have availble data, continue downloading and storing to local file
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
```

Comment: What does the FileUtils.copyURLToFile method look like?

Comment: It's a method from apache commons-io, but I tried in other ways, like the one I just added at the post. In the second try I added sysout to print the file size, but it's wrong, it's the size of the corrupted file, if I try to download the file from browser it will have a different size (a bigger size).

Comment: Looks like compressed content to me.

Comment: Yes, it is a .gz file, but if I try to open it using Winrar, it is corrupted, but if try to edit as text (opening with notepad++), it works (when I download the file from the browser), even if a change the extension from .gz to .xml it still works, but if I download the file programmatically, when I try to edit as text, it shows the content from the image.

Comment: So the browser is decompressing it.

Answer (score 0):

- Get rid of `setDoOutput(true)`. That changes the request from a GET to a POST, which destroys compatibility with what the browser is doing.
- Check the content-encoding response header. It looks like compressed data. If you don't want to deal with that, change the `Accept-encoding` request header to exclude it.
- You can also get rid of the `connect()` line. It is implicit in `getInputStream()` and several other methods you're calling.

Answer (score -1):

Questions:

You are calling the page as `GET` or `POST`? if it's `get`, so lines `urlConn.setDoInput(true);` and `urlConn.setDoOutput(true);` must be commented out, and use `openStream()` instead of `getInputStream()`
But if it's `post`, so no any data need to be passed, what about any header? setting `content-length`?!

First

```
while((l=is.read(buff))!=-1){/*instead of >0*/fos.write(buffer, 0, len);}
```

Second, initialize the file as

```
fos=new FileOutputStream(diretorio);
fos.getChannel().truncate(0);
```

Finally, make sure you flush the file

```
try{...
}finaly{fos.flush();fos.close()}
```

Or better use `try(<closable>){...}`

Zipped data, you may read out the data using `GZIPInputStream` instead of default/pure `InputStream`

```
GZIPInputStream is=new GZIPInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
```

Comment: None of these changes is necessary except possibly the last,a don several of them are wrong. There is no difference between `openStream()` and `openConnection.getInputStream()`; `read()` will never return zero unless the buffer is zero length; and `setDoInput(true)` merely asserts the default state.

Comment: @EJP so you don't believe in setting content-length for `post`, same about required data(if any), flushing the stream, and truncate the file before writing down?

Comment: No. I don't believe in any of it. It's all cargo-cult programming. `HttpURLConnection` sets the content-length automatically, and in this case there is no content. It's mean to be a GET. `flush()` before `close()` is redundant in all cases, and in this case it does nothing at all: see the Javadoc of `FileOutputStream`. A newly created file is already zero length, unless the `append` mode was specified, which it wasn't here, so truncating it is also redundant.